# React import svg file from another folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm currently inside a Navbar.jsx and I want to use one of my svg file (called "mushroom") inside the image folder. I have tried `import mushroom from "../../public/images/mushroom.svg"`. but that doesn't work. Here is the picture of my directory.

[My Project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GeewW.png)

_________________________________-
Update 11/13/2020:

I moved my image folder into src folder.

Now my Structure looks more like  this (* = folder) (~ = file)

```
*public
*src
   **components
         ~Navbar.js
   **images
         ~mushroom.svg
```

how do I import SVG file to Navbar.js?

Oh, think I got it.

```
import mushroom from "../images/mushroom.svg";
```

Comment: Check lerna. This could help: https://github.com/lerna/lerna . Also, try creating a component before using in another package.

Answer (score 0):

add your **image** folder inside **SRC** folder

->public  
->src 
   -> image 
  -> components

Comment: I moved my images folder into src folder. 

Now my Structure looks more like  this (* = folder) (~ = file) 
*public
*src
   **components
         ~Navbar.js
   **images
         ~mushroom.svg

Comment: import mushroom from "../images/mushroom.svg";